# PHPExcel setReadDataOnly is not working with Excel 2007

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel class to read .xls, .ods and .xlsx files, I need to ignore blank cells, even, if these cells have format.

I have used setReadDataOnly method to get it, and it's working fine with .xls and .ods files but it's not working with .xlxs files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "not working".

The setReadDataOnly(TRUE) option on read doesn't prevent blank cells from being read if the cell actually exists in the spreadsheet file, it simply means that it doesn't read the formatting for any of the cells... a blank cell is still a blank cell, and unless you create a read filter to prevent certain cells from being read, then they will still be loaded.

This behaviour is identical for xls, ods and for xlsx.

The only facility provided in PHPExcel to "skip" blank cells is within the Cell Iterator.

Comment: Thanks Mark, all clear about setReadDataOnly, but, my problem is that I have data in 10 rows (for example), in row 15 there is an empty cell with date format, then, phpexcel is taking the first 10 rows for xls files, is taking the first 10 rows for ods files, but for xlsx files is taking the first 15 rows, I need to ignore the rows with all its cells empty (higher than 10 row)

Comment: If you know that you only have 10 rows of data before loading the workbook, then you can set a Read Filter to load only those 10 rows. Section 4.3 of the "User Documentation - Reading" document shows how to apply a Read Filter.

Comment: Hmmmm, nope, 10 rows was an example I don't know how many rows will have my files, I need to ignore all rows with all cells empty, even, if these cells have format.

Comment: The only way to do that is to process them with your own logic... if the cell contains data (even an empty string) it exists in the file, and so will be loaded by PHPExcel. The alternative is to delete the empty rows in MS EXcel itself before saving the file. To find the last row in MS Excel, hit Ctrl-End when on that worksheet

Comment: pity it is not possible, I wanted to leave it as simple and easy to use, thanks! I will explain to end users. Thanks again. Regards.

Comment: Hey @Mark Baker, may be you may take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991249/phpexcel-together-cells-contain-same-data-issue