# PHPExcel together cells contain same data issue

Tags: php, phpexcel

While I am reading ods files (xls and xlsx are ok) using PHPExcel class and two cells are together and contain the same data, the second cell goes blank, Is it a bug? Here is my code:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../Librerias/phpexcel/Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$input_fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/bug.ods';
$input_file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($input_fileName);   
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($input_file_type);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true); 
$objPHPExcel = $reader->load($input_fileName);  
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();

$array_data = array();
foreach($rowIterator as $row){
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex ();    
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    }
}
echo '<pre>' ; print_r($array_data); echo '</pre>' ;
```

?>

Here is the content into bug.ods

```
  | A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F
-----------------------------------------------
1 | 1   |   1   |   2   |   2   |   3   |   3
2 | 2   |   2   |   1   |   1   |   3   |   3
3 | 3   |   3   |   1   |   1   |   2   |   2
4 | a   |   a   |   b   |   b   |   c   |   c
5 | b   |   b   |   a   |   a   |   c   |   c
6 | c   |   c   |   a   |   a   |   b   |   b
```

... and here is the print_r output.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => 1
            [B] => 
            [C] => 2
            [D] => 
            [E] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => 2
            [B] => 
            [C] => 1
            [D] => 
            [E] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [A] => 3
            [B] => 
            [C] => 1
            [D] => 
            [E] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [A] => a
            [B] => 
            [C] => b
            [D] => 
            [E] => c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [A] => b
            [B] => 
            [C] => a
            [D] => 
            [E] => c
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [A] => c
            [B] => 
            [C] => a
            [D] => 
            [E] => b
        )

)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

Some idea?

Comment: When you say `two cells are together` do you mean they are merged cells? Because if so this would be expected behaviour. When the cells are merged they effectively become one cell, so only have one value. The returned structure would show empty cells to keep the tabular layout correct. Arguably it would be better if the second "cell" was a reference to the first, but it is still a sensible approach...

Comment: Sorry for my english... I am ok, I meant, one cell next to another cell, not merge. like example above.

Answer (score 0):

Issue on PHPExcel issue tracker:
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/17471
This fixed for two values, but if value repeat rather than two times problem exist